# Programmatically change p12 certificate password?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, pkcs#12

Using the Google Cloud IAM api, i'm generating a PKCS12 private key for a service account.  By default, the key password is "notasecret".  How can I programmatically change it to something more secure?

```
import com.google.api.services.iam.v1.model.*;

Iam iam = googleIamClient(googleAppCredentials()); // helper method

String name = "projects/" + projectId + "/serviceAccounts/" + serviceAccountEmail;

CreateServiceAccountKeyRequest req = new CreateServiceAccountKeyRequest();
req.setPrivateKeyType("TYPE_PKCS12_FILE");

ServiceAccountKey key = iam.projects().serviceAccounts().keys().create(name, req).execute();

// equivalent to: byte[] privateKeyByteData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(serviceAccountKey.getPrivateKeyData());
byte[] privateKeyData = key.decodePrivateKeyData();

// what now?
```

Answer (score 5):

This will change the password for the Google Cloud IAM PKCS12 certificate, and can probably be generalized to others:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.*;

public byte[] changePKCS12KeyPassword(byte[] privateKeyData, String oldPassword, String newPassword) {
    try {
        KeyStore newKs = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        newKs.load(null, null);

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        ks.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(privateKeyData), oldPassword.toCharArray());
        Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();

        while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
            String alias = aliases.nextElement();
            Key privateKey = ks.getKey(alias, oldPassword.toCharArray());
            java.security.cert.Certificate[] certificateChain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
            newKs.setKeyEntry(alias, privateKey, newPassword.toCharArray(), certificateChain);
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        newKs.store(baos, newPassword.toCharArray());

        return baos.toByteArray();
    } catch (KeyStoreException
            | CertificateException
            | NoSuchAlgorithmException
            | UnrecoverableKeyException
            | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: This took many hours to figure out.  Hopefully this helps someone else!

Comment: Thanks @Fraser Harris.. You helped me a lot!